# How to find div by mutiple class

Tags: beautifulsoup

If I have a div like `<div class="a b c ">`
and another `<div class="a b">`
if I use `find('div',class_='a b')`
I will have both the div.
How can I just get one of the two?

Comment: which one should be selected? Also, post more context html

Answer (score 0):

Try using find_all on the specific class (worked for me).

```
soup.find_all("div", class_="a b c")
```

The above gives me just the a b c one.

```
soup.find_all("div", class_="a b")
```

While this returns just the a b one in my test.

If this doesn't work, consider finding out whether the containers appear in a particular order on the site. In that case you could just index the list you get from your function.